# Name resolution behind a proxy

Tags: linux, linux-networking

Using Linux (Debian)

At my current place of employment I'm behind an ISA proxy server, I'm not in a position to make any changes on this machine.

I'm developing software and have set up a virtual machine using kvm, almost everything works fine. The VM is on a virtual network 192.168.122.0

In /etc/profile I have the following environment variables:

```
http_proxy=http://x.x.x.x:8080/
no_proxy=localhost,192.168.122.0/24
```

I have the VM's name in /etc/hosts.

From the host I can ping the VM and connect via ssh by name.

I can't use a browser to connect to an apache server running on the VM, name resolution is passed to the ISA server and I get a failure displayed that the hostname could not be found (not surprised that corporate DNS doesn't know about my VM)..

I get the same in all browsers, so

```
elinks http://vmname
```

fails, even though

```
elinks -lookup vmname
```

returns the correct IP address for the VM.

However, "getent hosts vmname" returns the correct local IP for the VM.

If I do :

```
http_proxy="" elinks http://vmname
```

then I can connect via http fine.

Is there a configuration somewhere that I've missed? I've looked in /etc/nsswitch.conf & /etc/host.conf & /etc/resolv.conf

I notice that "host vmname" returns 2(SERVFAIL) rather than 3(NXDOMAIN).
Is it possible to configure this such that I can connect both to external servers & my internal VM without re-configuring the browser for each?

Comment: Do you want traffic to the VM to bypass the proxy, or go through the proxy but fix the DNS issue?

Comment: I want the traffic to the VM to bypass the proxy. The subnet the VM is on is in the no_proxy environment variable. Why do the browsers not get the address from /etc/hosts?

Answer (score 1):

Add the VM's name to the `no_proxy` variable.

```
no_proxy=localhost,192.168.122.0/24,vmname
```

And this should get you fixed.  Your problem is that all the browsers are sending the HTTP request to your ISA proxy.

Comment: Same as before, there are no http requests, the browsers are trying to get vmname from dns, failing & not trying /etc/hosts.

Answer (score 0):

First you should add the `<ip> vmname` to your local `/etc/hosts`

Then also add your local network in the broswer settings to be an exception for which it shouldn't use the proxy, like you seem to have done it in /etc/profile already.

Then it should work.

Comment: > I have the VM's name in /etc/hosts

Comment: When there is a proxy enabled, DNS resolution is done in the proxy not in the local machine.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a proxy, the DNS resolution is done in the proxy. You can't change that. Modifying /etc/hosts is useless. If the destination web server doesn't have virtualhosts, you can try connecting using the IP address. But if there are VirtualHosts, you can't do anything legal.